# I want to call a function when I scrolling an HTML element

Tags: html, scroll, onscroll

I want to call a function when I'm scrolling html id called section-2

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var elementTarget = document.getElementById("section-2");
  if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
      alert("You've scrolled past the second div");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hazard a guess it's not working because of the - dash symbol in the id section-2

Comment: I have changed it, But it also can't work

Comment: https://jsbin.com/conutumota/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Moz and its JS engine used in most non win browsers require parseInt() on many numeric properties returned from objects e.g. scrollY , Windows Jscript is kinder usually but it too carries a parseInt() and parseFloat() method.
However, another feature is the correct "script" enclosing tags for the html or xml document can cause trouble too dependent the documents DTD version E.g. XHTML 1.0 or HTML 4.01.

Try this in the document head tag.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  elementTarget = document.getElementById("section2");
  if ((parseFloat(window.scrollY)) > ((parseFloat(elementTarget.offsetTop)) + (parseFloat(elementTarget.offsetHeight)))) {
      alert("You've scrolled past the second div");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is nonsense from the start finish. Nothing requires `parseInt` on numeric properties. Mozilla's JS engine isn't used in "most non win browsers". The HTML version used has no effect on what script tags are correct for an embedded script. Removing a dash from the middle of an ID will have no effect.

Comment: You didn't read what I said, and the correct format of script tag for DTD of markup documents is required albeit rare to require to add the type="text/JavaScript" required for XHTML. Also parseInt() was included in both old JScript WSH engines and Netscape engines and W3C from standard engines and is there because loose typed language needs it.

Comment: "You didn't read what I said" — I did.

Comment: "the correct format of script tag for DTD of markup documents is required albeit rare to require to add the type="text/JavaScript" required for XHTML" — While HTML 4 and XHTML 1 do require a `type` attribute on the script (which is optional in HTML 5), omitting it makes no difference in this case. (And who is using HTML 4 / XHTML 1 in 2022 anyway?)

Comment: "Also parseInt() was included in" — `parseInt` has been a core part of JavaScript from the beginning … but isn't ever needed for `scrollY`, `offsetTop`, or `offsetHeight` because those properties return numbers, not strings.

Comment: "W3C" — is not responsible for the JavaScript specification or any JavaScript runtime.

Comment: You are wrong, DTD version decrees script tag must be in a particular format e.g. strict DTD XHTML, and the makers of script engines are not idiots that waste their time making useless superfluous algorithms such as you are saying of parseInt or parseFloat.

Comment: "DTD version decrees script tag must be on a particular format" — Yes, I said that. I also said that omitting the `type` attribute makes no difference. Browsers are very good at handling invalid HTML.

Comment: "and the makers of script engines are not idiots that waste their time making useless superfluous algorithms such as parseInt or parseFloat" — I never said `parseInt` was **never** useful. It is excellent for converting strings into numbers. It is completely pointless when you already have a number, as is the case here.

Comment: W3C Dom. Specs.

Comment: `parseInt` is defined by the ECMAScript specification, not by the DOM specification. It isn't part of DOM.

Comment: ECMA 262 I believe is updated to another now in the past few years.

Comment: ECMA-262 (not EVMA) is the JavaScript language specification which is published by ECMA not by the W3C. It is currently on version 13.

Comment: Phone typo on ECMA. If I looked at it your way the script would never work in some and not be "valid" XHTML Moreover without parseInt it would not work in DHTML, properties often need the prompt to number.

Comment: Which script? I haven't written any script. rakib53 wrote a script and asked a question about it. As per my comment on the question itself, their script **does** work.

Comment: "without parseInt it would not work" — As I have explained several times, and demonstrated in the link I just mentioned, **it does work without `parseInt`**.

Comment: "in DHTML" — DHTML is a buzzword meaning "Doing DOM stuff in JS". It mostly fell into disuse by the end of the last century. Why are you using it now?

Comment: "properties often need the prompt to number" — As I said several times, none of the properties  involved here are strings. They are defined (in the W3C specifications you mentioned!) as being numbers.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY    they do require that.

Comment: That says "returns the **number** of pixels" and "the returned value is a **double-precision floating-point**" makes no mention of `parseInt`. I have absolutely no idea how you came to the (wrong) conclusion that `parseInt` is needed.